# Datatables search box is not showing

Tags: jquery, datatables, search-box

I am using Datatables and I found that the searchbox is not appearing near the table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#dfUsageTable').DataTable({
                        pageLength: 10,
                        filter: true
                        deferRender:    true,
                        scrollY:        200,
                        scrollCollapse: true,
                        scroller:       true
                    });
                } );
```

I have tried adding filter option , but still it is not working.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq7049zs/)

Comment: are you looking for "searching: true"?

Comment: Comment out `//filter: true` and see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's too late, but hope it helps future visitors. add `"searching": true,` and put `,` after the `filter: true`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dfUsageTable').DataTable({
    pageLength: 10,
    filter: true,
    deferRender: true,
    scrollY: 200,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scroller: true,
    "searching": true,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Please use the following code, you were missing ',' on the third line.

```
$('#dfUsageTable').DataTable({
    pageLength: 10,
    filter: true,
    deferRender: true,
    scrollY: 200,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scroller: true
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit late, but I had a similar problem and none of the above helped.  What did help was removing a link to a stylesheet I had added called 'hamburger.css' for a hamburger menu.  When I removed that, all was fine.  So, my suggestion is to remove or comment out css files, except for those **required** by DataTables, one by one.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing that could happen:

It can be the case that you have the 'dom' property defined without the 'f' option (which controls the appearing of the input search box, [see](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)).

Quick way of testing this is just commenting the 'dom' property in your DataTable, so you can discard that it's something in the way you define it which is messing things up. (Default value, with the searchbox, would apply then).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible script link or CDN Conflict.
The problem could possibly arise from the inclusion of other script links or Content Delivery Networks (CDNs), such as jQuery, that are being loaded after the Datatable script. This can potentially cause conflicts and prevent the proper rendering of the search bar.
Try rearranging.

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/libs/datatables/datatables.min.js') }}"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Should change to the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/libs/datatables/datatables.min.js') }}"></script>
```